# How to check if input exist in the database. ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to check if the input `tbNRIC` exist in the database.

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string strNric = tbNRIC.Text;
    Session["nric"] = strNric;
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EADPRJConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader myReader = null;
            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("select PNRIC from Patient", con);

            myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                if (myReader[1].ToString() == tbNRIC.Text)
                {
                    flag = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (flag == true)
                Response.Write("<script>alert('Patient Profile Successfully Deleted');window.location ='ClientUpdate.aspx';</script>");
            else
                Response.Write("<script>alert('Patient Profile Unsuccessfully Updated');</script>");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And..? Your code does not work? Can you please be more specific? Your query does not _even_ have a `WHERE` clause to filtering.

Comment: Nope, it always returns me "Patient Profile Unsuccessfully Updated".

Comment: You are selecting one column but you are accessing the second-

Comment: It may be helpful if you add more detail about this problem such as the exact error message or what you have already tried to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

I *strongly* suspect you try to read second column since you write `myReader[1]`. A reader indexing is zero-based. You *might* need to change it as `myReader[0]`.

Also I prefer to use [`GetXXX` methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader_methods) of reader as a personal reference which I found it more readable.

```
if (myReader.GetString(0) == tbNRIC.Text)
```

Also use `using` statement to dispose your command and reader as you did for your connection.

Comment: It works perfectly! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You are accessing the second column with `myReader[1]` but you're selecting only one.

Use the `Where`-clause instead of reading all from the table. You could also use `ExecuteScalar` since you only want a single bool value:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EADPRJConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
{
    string sql = @"SELECT CAST(CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Patient
                                                WHERE PNRIC = @PNRIC)
                               THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS BIT)";

    using (var myCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
    {
        myCommand.Paramaters.Add("@PNRIC", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = tbNRIC.Text;
        con.Open();
        bool deleted = (bool)myCommand.ExecuteScalar();
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It will be better if You check patient existance without load all records from DB.

Do somthing like this:

```
SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("select PNRIC from Patient where PNRIC = @PNRIC", con);

myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PNRIC", tbNRIC.Text);
```

and check if you can read any row.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you apply the filter at Command Text. Something like :

```
var strsql = "select PNRIC from Patient where PNRIC='"+ tbNRIC.Text + "'";
SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(strsql , con);
....

var flag = false;
myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

if(myReader .HasRows)  flag = true;
```

Comment: While I agree with the idea the execution of concatenating a user input into a query string opens up the possibility of sql injection.  Better to use parameters instead.

Comment: Right ! I just gave the idea to resolve the problem. I hope developer will take care of that . :)